# Filter "#N/A# rows to eliminate them in a short period of time

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an excel which has about 500000 rows.
I have one sheet called "B" where is all the info and I only need the rows where the column Y contains text, not de #N/A from the LOOKUP.
I have to copy the rows with info, to another sheet called "A".
I used this code for the same process

```
On Error Resume Next
Columns("Y").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

But in this case, there are many rows so it takes 5 minutes(not worthy)

I only have 3000 rows with non NA, so I thought it will be easier to filter them and copy to "A" the entire row(the column A from the row in "B" it's not necessary, and the destination sheet "A" the column A has to be empty).
I don't know how to do it, i'm new in this language, thank you

[Sheet B; the column Y with the header SKU contains the not found and the found ones ex:SKU1233444](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNZ8V.png)

[Sheet A;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJDBg.png)

I have to copy from B except headers and column A, all the rows with SKU found and paste them into Sheet A leaving its headers and the column A empty because it's formulated

Comment: [this](https://vbacompiler.com/optimize-vba-code/) might help, to optimize performance

Comment: You should be able to do this using the `ISNA()` function and applying a filter without having to use VBA.

Comment: Why don't you share the exact location of your data, e.g. `A1:ZLastRow` in worksheet `B`, and where you want to put it e.g. `B1:AALastRow` (minus the error rows) in worksheet `A`? If you have a code used to copy the whole thing from `B` to `A`, please share it. Also, a screenshot of your worksheet(s) would be helpful. Share the additional information by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73553402/edit) at any time.

Comment: Thomas C. thanks for the info, but it takes still many time

Comment: VBasic2008 I edited the post to be clearer, if you still have any doubt, contact me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arrays work faster than deleting rows one by one in VBA

Arrays need to be transposed / flipped before they're pasted into a worksheet

I ran the code below and it works.

I assumed that we're only working from column B as your attached photo above seems to suggest

Option Explicit ensures that we declare all variables we use.

$ is short hand for string; % for integer; & for long

```vb
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub Test()
    
    Dim sChar$, sRange$, sRange2$
    Dim iCol%, iLastUsedCol%
    Dim iLastUsedRow&, iRow&
    Dim r As Range
    Dim aCleaned As Variant, aData As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B")
    
    With WS
        'furthest column to right on a worksheet
        sChar = ColumnChars2(Columns.Count)
        'last used header column on this sheet
        iLastUsedCol = .Range(sChar & 1).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'last used row of data on this sheet
        iLastUsedRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'cells containing data
        sRange = "B2:" & ColumnChars2(iLastUsedCol) & iLastUsedRow
        'transferring data to array
        aData = .Range(sRange)
    End With
    
    'temporary store for row of data
    ReDim aParam(iLastUsedCol - 2)
    'cleaned data
    ReDim aCleaned(iLastUsedCol - 2, 0)
    'setting first entry of cleaned data to blank initially - needed for AddEntry subroutine called below
    aCleaned(0, 0) = ""
    
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(aData)
        'if Y column cell for this row does not contain error
        If Not IsError(aData(iRow, 24)) Then
        
            'save entire row temporarily
        
            For iCol = 0 To UBound(aParam)
                aParam(iCol) = aData(iRow, iCol + 1)
            Next
            
            'transfer saved row to cleaned data array
        
            Call AddEntry(aCleaned, aParam)
        End If
    Next
    
    With WS2
        iLastUsedCol = .Range(sChar & 1).End(xlToLeft).Column
        iLastUsedRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'if data in B sheet
        If iLastUsedRow > 1 Then
            sRange2 = "B2:" & ColumnChars2(iLastUsedCol) & iLastUsedRow
            'empty
            .Range(sRange2).ClearContents
        End If
        
        Set r = .Range("B2")
        'copy cleaned data to sheet B
        r.Resize(UBound(aCleaned, 2) + 1, UBound(aCleaned, 1) + 1).Value = my_2D_Transpose(aCleaned)
    End With
        
    End Sub
```

The first subroutine called by the test routine above:

```vb
    Public Function ColumnChars2(iCol As Variant) As String
    
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    
    '
    ' calculates character form of column number
    '
    
    Dim iPrePrefix As Integer, iPrefix As Integer, iSuffix As Integer
    
    iSuffix = iCol
    iPrefix = 0
    Do Until iSuffix < 27
        iSuffix = iSuffix - 26
        iPrefix = iPrefix + 1
    Loop
    iPrePrefix = 0
    Do Until iPrefix < 27
        iPrefix = iPrefix - 26
        iPrePrefix = iPrePrefix + 1
    Loop
    ColumnChars2 = IIf(iPrePrefix = 0, "", Chr(64 + iPrePrefix)) & IIf(iPrefix = 0, "", Chr(64 + iPrefix)) & Chr(64 + iSuffix)
    
    Exit Function
    Exit_Label:
      On Error Resume Next
      Application.Cursor = xlDefault
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Exit Function
    Err_Handler:
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ColumnChars2"
      Resume Exit_Label
    
    End Function
```

The second subroutine called by the test routine above:

```vb
    Public Sub AddEntry(aList As Variant, aEntry As Variant)
    
    '
    ' build array for later copy onto sheet
    '
    
    Dim i%
    Dim aEntry2 As Variant
    
    If VarType(aEntry) = vbString Then
        aEntry2 = Array(aEntry)
    Else
        aEntry2 = aEntry
    End If
    
    If aList(0, 0) <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve aList(0 To UBound(aEntry2), 0 To UBound(aList, 2) + 1)
    End If
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(aEntry2)
        aList(i, UBound(aList, 2)) = aEntry2(i)
    Next
                
    End Sub
```

The third subroutine called by the test routine above:

```vb
    Function my_2D_Transpose(arr As Variant)
    
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    
    'works better than delivered Application.Transpose function
    
    Dim a&, b&, tmp As Variant
    
    ReDim tmp(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2), LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1))
    
    For a = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For b = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            tmp(b, a) = arr(a, b)
        Next b
    Next a
    
    my_2D_Transpose = tmp
    
    Exit Function
    Exit_Label:
      On Error Resume Next
      Application.Cursor = xlDefault
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Exit Function
    Err_Handler:
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "my_2D_Transpose"
      Resume Exit_Label
    End Function
```

Comment: If Not IsError(aData(iRow, 24)) Then            Error 9, subsubscript out of range

Comment: @Oscar. Did you run the code above and receive this error you mentioned?

Comment: @Oscar if you got an error, you can debug and find out what row this is happening at, by looking at the value of iRow, and then share the contents of cell Y for that row.

Comment: don't know how to find out

Comment: @Oscar when you get an error in VBA, a small panel appears with three buttons; End Debug and Help. If you click on Debug, you'll be able to interrogate the live code. If you hover over the word iRow, you'll be able to see it's value. If you add one to that value, you'll have the row in your data, where the error happened.

Comment: I did a simulation here: the contents of all target cells in B were deleted. But the valid ones were not copied to A.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Criteria Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNoErrors()
    
    ' Define constants.
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "B"
    Const CritColumnString As String = "Y"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg') excluding the first column
    ' and the headers.
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        cCount = .Columns.Count - 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount, cCount).Offset(1, 1)
    End With
    
    ' Determine the criteria column ('CritColumn') which has to be reduced
    ' by one due to the shifting of the source range
    ' which is starting in column 'B'.
    Dim CritColumn As Long
    CritColumn = sws.Columns(CritColumnString).Column - 1
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to a 2D one-based array ('Data').
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, dr As Long
    
    ' Write the rows, not containing the error value in the criteria column,
    ' to the top of the array.
    For sr = 1 To rCount
        If Not IsError(Data(sr, CritColumn)) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For sc = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, sc) = Data(sr, sc)
            Next sc
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    ' Reference the destination range ('drg'), a range with the same address
    ' as the source range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(srg.Address)
    
    With drg
        ' Write the values from the top of the array to the destination range.
        .Resize(dr).Value = Data
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).ClearContents
    End With
         
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```